# Trying to change this from an image to a button, when I change it to look like a button I lose functionality

Tags: php, html, forms, button, input

I am losing functionality when I change from an image to a simple button. This is the code when it is an image and it submits:

```
$form= "
          <form method='post' action='/login.php'>
            <b>Name:</b><br><input type='text' name='name'
            size='19' class='login'><br><b>Password:</b><br><input
            type='password' name='password' size='19' class=
            'login'><br>
             <img src='/layout/blank.gif' height='6' width='1'
            alt='blank'><br>
                        <input type='hidden' name='redir' value='$redir'> 
             <input type='image' src='/layout/loginword.gif' name=
            'action' value='Go' style='vertical-align: middle;'
            title='Login'> (<a href='/lostdetails.php' class=
            'menu'>Lost Details?</a>)
          </form>";
```

When edited to display a button instead of an image as below I lose the functionality:

```
$form= "
      <form method='post' action='/login.php'>
        <b>Name:</b><br><input type='text' name='name'
        size='19' class='login'><br><b>Password:</b><br><input
        type='password' name='password' size='19' class=
        'login'><br>
         <img src='/layout/blank.gif' height='6' width='1'
        alt='blank'><br>
                    <input type='hidden' name='redir' value='$redir'> 
         <input type='button' name=
        'action' value='Go' style='vertical-align: middle;'
        title='Login'> (<a href='/lostdetails.php' class=
        'menu'>Lost Details?</a>)
      </form>";
```

Comment: Hi! Could you please post the non-working script after you put the button instead of the image? So that is simpler to figure this out. Thanks!

Comment: @Andrea thank you, I have edited the post.

Comment: check my answer, see if that works :)

Comment: no problem. I just edited my answer with some additional information: check it out :) happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `type="button"` in the submitting input! Try to use `type="submit"` in that "Go" field.

That's because the first attribute value prompt to the browser that the button is literally a normal object which doesn't have nothing to do with that form. Maybe you can use it as a **link**, or a **Javascript** event caller ... but not as the submitting action.

So the new code will be:

```
<form method='post' action='/login.php'>
    <b>Name:</b><br><input type='text' name='name'
    size='19' class='login'><br><b>Password:</b><br><input
    type='password' name='password' size='19' class=
    'login'><br>
     <img src='/layout/blank.gif' height='6' width='1'
    alt='blank'><br>
                <input type='hidden' name='redir' value='$redir'> 
     <input type='submit' name=
    'action' value='Go' style='vertical-align: middle;'
    title='Login'> (<a href='/lostdetails.php' class=
    'menu'>Lost Details?</a>)
</form>
```

Obviously you can put it in you PHP variable, your choice. If you want to learn more about HTML buttons, [**here**](https://www.w3schools.com/Tags/tag_button.asp) you can see the W3Schools documentation about it.

Andrea

Answer (score 1):

This is occuring because `input type="image"` has the same functionality of a `submit` button, while `input type="button"` does not have any implicit functionality. (It is just a dumb clickable button)

You need to change it to `input type="submit"`

Answer (score 0):

you should use type="submit"

and if you want to use the button,
you should use the button tag

with type="submit"